# How to answer this question without using log.

Tags: exponential-function

I have seen this question before, but I just can solve finding $x=y=1$, but the book tells me another answer, where $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=2$.

This is the question. Find the solution of the system of equations where $x^y=\frac{1}{y^2}$ and $y^x=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite these as $x^y = y^{-2}$ and $y^x = x^{-1/2}$, then express $x$, say:
$$x=(y^x)^{-2}$$
then plug it into the other: 
$$(y^x)^{-2y} = y^{-2} $$
then either $y=1$ or $-2xy=-2$
and you can do similarly for the other one, with base $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$I\;\;\;x^y=y^{-2}$$

$$II\;\;\;y^x=x^{-1/2}$$

$$ x^{yx}=y^{-2x}=(y^x)^{-2}=(x^{-1/2})^{(-2)}=x\Longrightarrow xy=1\Longrightarrow$$

$$I\;\;\;\Longrightarrow x^{1/x}=(x^{-1})^{-2}=x^2\Longrightarrow x=\frac{1}{2}\,\,,\,\,y=2$$

Comment: That last step is incomplete. $x$ can be 1.

Comment: Yes, of course: the trivial answer $\,x=y=1\,$ that the OP already found before.

Comment: Oh sorry I overlooked.